# pkg-buildpackage: error: failed to sign .buildinfo file

Tags: 20.04, dpkg, debian-installer

Update 7/28/2021: I ignore both errors mentioned below, assuming I understand the why of both (see below) and succeeded installing the debhelper version 13.2.1 and the COTURN version 4.5.2r3 in Ubuntu 20.04.2. It is working with no problem. I still would love an expert to confirm my assumptions or correct me. Thanks.

Original question: I am trying to install [COTURN 4.5.2r3](https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/coturn/download) in UBUNTU 20.04 because of the bugs in the previous version that prevents it from handling port 443 for SSL communications, required for an efficient WebRCT TURN server. In the midst of doing that I discovered that the new distribution has a dependency on the library debhelper-compat (=13), but the 20.04.2 version of Ubuntu (latest current stable version) only updates to version 12 of debhelper-compat.

When building debhelper-compat from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debhelper/13.2.1ubuntu1) (Note: I used version 13.2.1 for being the one that comes with Ubuntu 20.10). I followed the following method:

1.- Installed dpkg-dev package:
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
dpkg-source -x yourfile.dsc

got error about missing key, to check .dsc file, but I checked the sha256 checksum signature of the dsc file (is this correct? safe? comments?)
cd package_directory
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b

and here I got the following info messages and afterwards errors:
pkg-genchanges: info: binary-only upload (no source code included)

```
 dpkg-source --after-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: binary-only upload (no source included)
 signfile debhelper_13.2.1ubuntu1_amd64.buildinfo
gpg: skipped "Gianfranco Costamagna <locutusofborg@debian.org>": No secret key
gpg: dpkg-sign.i0iFX8VO/debhelper_13.2.1ubuntu1_amd64.buildinfo: clear-sign failed: No secret key

dpkg-buildpackage: error: failed to sign .buildinfo file
```

My non-expert understanding is that this created the correct package whose .building file is correct but unsigned. Thus I won't (nor do I want to) be able to publish it anywhere.

Thus, I'd be safe to execute the following command:

dpkg -i ../yourfile_arch.deb

And then move ahead with the installation of Coturn 4.5.2r3.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: https://nimblecoders.in/install-coturn-in-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: Thanks! The tutorial above doesn't apply, it will install the older version of COTURN 4.5.1.1 with the known bugs and also without support for reverse proxy, so it won't work for ports 443 and 80 unless you are not running a server that is already binding those ports.